# What's the point of making a new typedef for each variable?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

The title is a little exxagerated, but I still don't understand it.

As a most basic example, take the `size_t` type from `time.h`:

> size_t <...> is defined in the  header file (among
>   others) as an unsigned integral type.

What's the point of even renaming `unsigned int` to `size_t`? Such things often make the code harder to understand, because they make a developer look for those type declarations to understand even if it's a basic type renamed, or maybe some class/struct. Yet I see this being done a lot in different libraries.

Comment: I agree typedefs can make it more difficult to read code because you have to keep looking up to see what something is. Microsoft's MFC has typdefs of typedefs of typedefs. By the time you find out what the thing really is, you forgot what the original name was.

Comment: in 32 bit systems size_t is 4 bytes, in 64 bit systems size_t will be 8 bytes, but int will still be of 4 bytes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What's the point of even renaming unsigned int to size_t? Such things
>   often make the code harder to understand

1. It makes code *easier* to understand, you immediately know what the object represents, "*it's some sort of size*". Compare that to a bare `int`. The real underlying type is of no immediate concern: **as long as you don't know it your code remains portable**
2. Today it may be an `unsigned int` but maybe tomorrow it's going to be an `unsigned long long`. As long as your program uses the right types it's future-proof

> they make a developer look for those type declarations

Don't look: you'll be tempted to do non-portable things with it. Think of it the way you'd think of a C++ `std::string`. You know what it does, you know how to use it but you don't really know what's inside.

Answer (score 11):

`size_`t is used to ensure **[portability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability)**. `size_t` is not always *"unsigned int"*, but it is the size that can represent the largest possible object on the given platform.

Answer (score 2):

For a low-level library such as the standard C library, `typedef` are important to increase user programs portability; there is no debate.

On the other side, using alias in your programs is an interesting question. There are essentially two reasons :

- to simplify your expressions, e.g. a pointer to function or an agreggate;
- to introduce an abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the types can give you a better clue as to what the variable represents. Instead of just seeing a bunch if ints laying around, types like std::size_t, std::ptrdiff_t, etc. tell you more about what's going on.